# Accessing network shared file while using windows authentication in firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firefox, iis, impersonation

A MVC web app, hosted in IIS with Windows Authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation, accesses a shared network location and lists the files shared to the current user. Its working from chrome and not working when a Firefox is used.

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

This returns the current user in both cases. But when Firefox is used, Access is denied to the shared location.

EDIT:
The issue in firefox is fixed but now MS Edge has the same problem

Comment: At a guess I'd say this might be because Firefox connects to IIS using NTLM and not Kerberos, and therefore there is no onward Kerberos token available to use for connecting to the network share. Not much you can do about that. Is it really necessary to impersonate the user when doing this? Can't the network share just be made available to the account under which the IIS Application Pool is running?

Comment: There are multiple users with access to different files...

Comment: You can still write code to work out which files the user has access to based on the access control rules, and then return only those files. That doesn't mean you have to physically use their identity to access them.

Answer (score 0):

Type in about:config in firefox address bar

Whitelist your uris in

```
network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris, 
network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris, 
network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Integrated_authentication